# Most efficient algorithm to print 1-100 using a given random number generator

Tags: algorithms, integers, randomness, random-number-generator

We are given a random number generator `RandNum50` which generates a random integer uniformly in the range 1–50.
We may use only this random number generator to generate and print all integers from 1 to 100 in a random order. Every number must come exactly once, and the probability of any number occurring at any place must be equal.

What is the most efficient algorithm for this?

Comment: Use an array/or bit vector to record the numbers already seen and a counter to record the number of unique numbers seen.

Comment: @DaveClarke
How can I generate a number bigger than 50 with that?
If I use it more than 1 time, then also, how will I generate 1 using them?

Comment: The challenge of course is ensuring that all places occur with equal likelihood. You could use  `RandNum100 = (RandNum50() * 2) - (RandNum50 > 25) ? 0 : 1)`.

Comment: @DaveClarke: So you propose iterated rejection sampling? That would terminate only in expectation.

Comment: I was merely giving a hint.

Comment: @Raphael: I suggest rereading Dave's suggestion.  There is no need to reject anything.  You have uniform probability for any even in [2, 100] with his first subexpression, and uniform probability at subtracting 1 (with no overlaps here).  Look at the decision tree for any [1, 100].  It's uniform.  You could also subtract RandNum50 (mod 2) or a variety of other alternates.  Rejection is useful (but again not necessary) when you don't have such obvious division alignments and you have to avoid pigeonhole binning, but here it's easy to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought (so it can be wrong :-) of this $O(N^2)$ solution that uses the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). In order to keep uniform distribution with *good approximation* (see EDIT section below) at every iteration you can use this trick  to produce a value `krand` between $0$ and $k-1$:

```
 // return a random number in [0..k-1] with uniform distribution
 // using a uniform random generator in [1..50]
 funtion krand(k) {    
   sum = 0
   for i = 1 to k do sum = sum + RandNum50() - 1
   krand = sum mod k
 }
```

The Fisher-Yates algorithm becomes:

```
arr : array[0..99]
for i = 0  to 99 do arr[i] = i+1; // store 1..100 in the array
for i = 99 downto 1 {
  r = krand(i+1)  // random value in [0..i]
  exchange the values of arr[i] and arr[r]
}
for i = 0 to 99 do print arr[i]
```

#### EDIT:

As pointed out by Erick the `krand` function above doesn't return a truly uniform distribution. There are other methods that can be used to get a better (arbitrarily better) and faster approximation; but (up to my knowledge) the only way to get a truly uniform distribution is to use the [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling): pick $m = \lceil \log_2(k) \rceil$ random bits and if the number $r$ obtained is less than $k$ return it, otherwise generate another random number; a possible implementation:

```
function trulyrand(k) {
    if (k <= 1) return 0
    while (true) { // ... if you're really unlucky ...
      m = ceil(log_2 (k) ) // calculate m such that k < 2^m
      r = 0  // will hold the random value
      while (m >= 0) {  // ... will add m bits        
        if ( rand50() > 25 ) then b = 1 else b = 0   // random bit
        r = r * 2 + b  // shift and add the random bit
        m = m - 1
      }      
      if (r < k) then return r  // we have 0<=r<2^m ; accept it, if r < k
    }
}
```

Comment: The wikipedia page you link to states that there is an $O(n)$ variant.

Comment: @DaveClarke: thnks, the solution I posted is the first that came to my mind (and I'm not truly convinced that it is correct :-) I'll soon read the Wikipedia page to see how to solve the bias problem more efficiently.

Comment: I think "shuffle" is the key buzzword here.

Comment: Vor & Raphael
Thanks for the reply guys.
And yes, shuffle is the keyword (buzzword) here.
When I got around this problem, this condition was put forward me, that there shouldn't be any shuffling.
But according to me, the answer is awesome.
Thanks @Vor

Comment: The trick in krand(k) does not produce a truly uniform distribution, although it is a good approximation: even for k=3 this gives a 33.333328% chance of outputting 0.  Is there a justification for summing all the way up to k here?  I would think a smaller limit suffices if we just want an approximation.

Comment: @ErickWong: you are right; I think that the true uniform distribution can only be reached using the rejection sampling method which is not guaranteed to end in constant time. There are other approximation schemes (that allows to reach any desired approximation), the one I proposed is the first that came to my mind.

Comment: @Vor: You do not need any rejection sampling here.  You have a uniform 1-50.  You can make a uniform 1-100 using Dave Clark's suggestion on the main question's comments.  Reread that suggestion.  It is uniform without any rejections.

Comment: @ex0du5: I know that, but how do you produce a uniform random permutation of numbers [1..100] using only a uniform random generator in [1..100]? The only alternative method I know is: step1) pick a random value $r$ in $1..100$; step2) if $r$ has already been picked then discard it and goto step1; step3) print $r$; step4) if we have not printed all the 100 numbers goto step1. But this method simply shifts  the rejection to the already picked elements.

Comment: @ex0du5: In fact, it's provably impossible to do so - see my answer for details.

Answer (score 4):

Since other folks have given approximate solutions and solutions involving taking indeterminate numbers of deviates, how about a proof that there is no such algorithm that's guaranteed to only require a finite number of `RandNum50()` calls?

As others have noted, printing the numbers from 1-100 in random order is equivalent to printing a random permutation of these numbers; there are 100! of these permutations, and so any particular permutation must be output with probability $\frac{1}{100!}$.

But if we knew that our algorithm used at most $k$ calls to `RandNum50` for some $k$, then we could argue as follows: firstly, pad out those computation paths that make fewer than $k$ calls to `RandNum50` to make additional dummy calls (that is, calls where the returned value is irrelevant), so that all computation paths make precisely $k$ calls.  Any given sequence of $k$ results from our calls to `RandNum50` must result in some output permutation, and so we can build an 'outcomes table' that maps any given sequence $(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_k)$ of results from our calls into a particular output permutation.  Since each of these outcomes is equally likely (each of them has probability $\displaystyle\frac{1}{50^k}$), then the probability of getting any particular permutation out of our algorithm must be of the form $\displaystyle\frac{c}{50^k}$ for some $c$.  But $\displaystyle\frac{1}{100!}$ can't be of this form, because $100!$ doesn't divide $50^k$ for any $k$ (for instance, 3 divides $100!$ but can't divide any number of the form $50^k$).  This means that no possible distribution of outcomes to random-number calls can produce a uniform permutation.

Answer (score 3):

The previous solutions are not optimal. The complexity is exactly $n\log n + O(1)$ in calls to RandNum50 and is described in some detail [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11894/how-to-generate-a-permutation-uniformly-by-using-an-one-bit-uniform-random-gener), using as a source of random bit (as suggested by Vor):

```
if ( rand50() > 25 ) then b = 1 else b = 0   // random bit
```

The basic idea is that you save a lot of bits if you generate a uniform between $1$ and $n!$, and then using [factorial base decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_base), instead of generating a sequence of uniforms ranged up to $1$, then $2$, then $3$, etc., $n$. This is actually, as I mention in the post, the topic of a paper I have submitted!

If you do not know how to generate a uniform, as suggested in that post, from a random bit, you could also generate an approximation of the uniform directly, in this way (which is equivalent to Vor's "trulyrand", but faster):

```
P = (RandNum50()-1) + (RandNum50()-1)*50^1 + (RandNum50()-1)*50^2 + ...
```

going as far as you need to go. This is developing $P$ in base $50$. Then simply truncate $P$, i.e., $Q=P\mod n$, in your case $n=100!$. This value is not completely random, but it is a measure of uniformity that is often used. Or, as Vor suggests, you can reject if $P>n$. Then with this value, you can do the factorial base expansion as described in the [post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11894/how-to-generate-a-permutation-uniformly-by-using-an-one-bit-uniform-random-gener).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done the analysis to confirm how uniform (or not) this would be, and it could be adjusted to be a true shuffle, but could you just choose, from a starting array of the `i`th index = `i + 1`, the `(k + RandNum50() + RandNum50() - 1) mod (100 - k)` index, with removal, for `k` = 0..99?

This "pushes" the peak in the `RandNum50() + RandNum50()` distribution forward uniformly.

<sub>I'm pretty sure this is not quite right as I've stated it because the 0 index (1) is not obtainable from the first choice and I cannot quickly see an alternative 1..50 + 1..50 adjustment that produces 0..99.</sub>

**Update**

To fix the issue I noted, I effectively used `RandNum100` as mentioned in the question comments to randomally initialise the first `k` offset.

This produces a distribution with a significant wave at the front.

Instead of advancing by 1 I used another `RandNum50` to increment that first `k`. This produces a result that is random enough for me, but it is still not "truly" random, as can be easily seen if you change K to 2.

[Testing VB.NET code](http://pastebin.com/LiJY3v7x) where I catered for any even K. Note it is O(K), 6K+2 in fact.